# TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to write code to find two indices when a value changes from 0 to 1 and save that value in a variable called `idx`. Then, the two rows before and after the index should be extracted and processed. The code for extracting the rows is included below:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,3,4,7,8,11,1,15,20,15,16,87],
                 'B':[1,3,4,6,8,11,1,19,20,15,16,87],
                 'flag':[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0]})
         
N = 2
s = [x for s, e in zip(idx-N,idx) for x in range(s, e+1)]
df_before_2rows=df1.loc[df1.index.intersection(s)]
```

This works. But, if I run this in a for-loop that processes each index one-by-one then I get an error:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,3,4,7,8,11,1,15,20,15,16,87],
                     'B':[1,3,4,6,8,11,1,19,20,15,16,87],
                     'flag':[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0]})

for item in idx:
    N = 2
    s = [x for s, e in zip(item-N,item) for x in range(s, e+1)]
    df_before_2rows=df1.loc[df1.index.intersection(s)]
```

```
TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration
```

Main goal is to get two rows before when flag change from 0 to 1 and process ,and then go next check if flag change from 0 to 1 then do same as above

Comment: what is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can choose a different approach using `groupby` with `cumsum` of `diff`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,3,4,7,8,11,1,15,20,15,16,87],
                 'B':[1,3,4,6,8,11,1,19,20,15,16,87],
                 'flag':[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0]})

for _, i in df.groupby(df["flag"].shift(1).diff().eq(1).cumsum()):
    if i["flag"].eq(1).any(): # this is done to skip the last group with no flag of 1
        print (i.tail(3))
        # do your thing with i.tail(3)...
```

EDIT using your original method:

```
idx = [4,8] # I assume you retrieved the idx already

for item in idx:
    N = 2
    df_before_2rows=df.loc[range(item-N,item+1)]
    print (df_before_2rows)
```

Comment: @ Henry Yik   , i want to use my own method , just want to know where need change code to remove Type error

Comment: `for item in idx` iterates over the items in idx which should be `int`. You can't `zip` an `int`. Simply do `range(item-N, item+1)` will achieve what you wanted 
@Edward .

Answer (score 0):

`item` is an element of `idx`; `item-N` is also just a number, hence the error.

```
for item in idx:
    N = 2
    s = [x for s, e in zip(item-N,item) for x in range(s, e+1)]
```

simplifies to:

```
for item in idx:
    N = 2
    # s = [x for x in range(item-N, item+1)]
    s = list(range(item-N, item+1))
    # s = np.arange(item-N, item+1)
```